# mongodb - filter out some values when doing $unwind

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following Customer Order data in mongodb

```
 "_id" : 7,
 "customer name" : "John Smith",
 "OrderItem" : [
         {
                 "product_category" : "Mobile",
                 "price" : 900
         },
         {
                 "product_category" : "Computer",
                 "price" : 4200.48
         },
         {
                 "product_category" : "TV",
                 "price" : 670.20
         },
         {
                 "product_category" : "TV",
                 "price" : 960.52
         }
 ]
```

I need to average each product category to be like this:

```
 "_id" : 7,
 "customer name" : "John Smith",
 "OrderItem" : [
         {
                 "product_category" : "Mobile",
                 "price" : 900
         },
         {
                 "product_category" : "Computer",
                 "price" : 4200.48
         },
         {
                 "product_category" : "TV",
                 "price" : 815.36
         }
 ]
```

i tried to use $unwind but not sure how to group them . any help ?

Comment: How exactly have you tried it?

Comment: `product_category` or `product_name` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/)** with a pipeline which consists of the following stages: a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operation in the first pipeline stage filters the document stream to allow only matching documents (document with `_id = 7` in your case) to pass unmodified into the next pipeline stage, which is the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operation. This deconstructs the desired `OrderItem` array field from the input documents to output a document for each element that you can then group on and do the aggregation operation of finding the average of the category prices. The next stage in the pipeline is the $group operation which then groups input documents by `product_category` and applies the [**`$avg`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg) expression to each group on the `price`. The last stage [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) then reshapes each document in the stream to produce the desired outcome. Thus your aggregation would look like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {"_id": 7}
    },
    {   
        "$unwind": "$OrderItem"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$OrderItem.product_category",
            "average_price": {
                "$avg": "$OrderItem.price"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "product_category" : "$_id",
            "average_price": 1
        }

    }
])
```

**Result**:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "average_price" : 4200.48,
            "product_category" : "Computer"
        }, 
        {
            "average_price" : 815.36,
            "product_category" : "TV"
        }, 
        {
            "average_price" : 900,
            "product_category" : "Mobile"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should unwind `OrderItem` then group them and [mongo $avg](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) to calculate avarage. Below aggregation will calculate avg

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate(
                    {"$match":{"customer name":"John Smith"}}, // match specified  customername  
                    {"$unwind":"$OrderItem"}, // unwind the OrderItem

                    {"$group":{"_id":"$OrderItem.product_category",
                       "avg":  {"$avg":"$OrderItem.price"} // mongo avg method used for avrage
                }}
              ).pretty()
```

So above query return following results

```
{ "_id" : "Computer", "avg" : 4200.48 }
{ "_id" : "TV", "avg" : 815.36 }
{ "_id" : "Mobile", "avg" : 900 }
```

But above result not match your given expected output, so you should group twice to get exact output

```
        db.collectionName.aggregate(
                {"$match":{"customer name":"John Smith"}},  //match given criteria
                {"$unwind":"$OrderItem"},           //unwind $OrderItem

                {"$group":{"_id":"$OrderItem.product_category",
                           "customerName":{"$first":"$customer name"}, // group all data with calculating avg
                           "id":{"$first":"$_id"}, 
                               "avg":{"$avg":"$OrderItem.price"}}},

                    {"$group":{"_id":"$id",
                       "customer Name":{"$first":"$customerName"},
                           "OrderItem":{"$push":   {"product_category":"$_id","price":"$avg"}}}} // group them for expected output

               ).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$OrderItem"},
    {$group: {
        _id: {id: "$_id", cat: "$OrderItem.product_category"}, 
        name: {$first: "$customer name"}, 
        price: {$avg: "$OrderItem.price"}
    }}, 
    {$group: {
        _id: "$_id.id", 
        OrderItem: {$push: {product_category: "$_id.cat", price: "$price"}}, 
        "customer name": {$first: "$name"}
    }}
])
```